# How do I supress blank fields when doing a mail merge in word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I am creating a mail merge in word 2016 with data from an Excel 2016 file.  I would like to do 2 things.

1) set it up so that records with only 1 address line does not print a blank, while records with 2 address lines display both
2) There are records with blank fields and I would like to not display blanks on those letters.

Comment: For question 2, you don't want to display blank but there is no data... what **do** you want displayed?

Comment: I guess the best way to describe it, is, I would like it to ignore the field.

Comment: For example, if the excel file has a column for address line 2, but that field is blank, I would like it to display on the word doc as:

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1:

A second address may or may not exist. If it does not exist, do not print the blank line.

In your spreadsheet you should compress your addresses into a single cell (each). Instead of `<<Street>> <<City>> <<State>> <<Zip>>` through four cells you can concatenate those four into a single cell using line breaks by pressing `ALT-Enter` - in the formula I will call this {AE}:

Assuming the addresses are found in A2-D2
`=concatenate("{AE}{AE}",A2,"{AE}",B2," ",C2," ",D2)`

Using this method you can place this adjacent to the first address and it will begin with a line-break putting it on the next line:

`<<Address 1>> <<Address 2>>`

will show as...

```
123 Street Name    
Cityville, Statestown 12345

456 Road Ave.
Towntown, Provinceton 67890
```

thanks to the two line breaks at the beginning of the second address.

### Question 2:

Same as above, apply the spacing and line breaks you would like to see in the merged document within the **spreadsheet** instead of the Word doc.